# How do we evaluate Double Summation with independant indices?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How can we show that this double sum is equal to product of single sum?

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_ia_j = \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i\right)^2$$

I tried like this, that for the inner sum, we can take $a_i$ common:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left[a_i\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j\right)\right]$$
Then for outer sum we can take $\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j\right)$ common to get:

$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i\right)\times\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}a_j\right) = \left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i\right)^2$$

Is this method ok? Also give some insights on double sums and how to evaluate them! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your reasoning looks perfectly sound to me.

Comment: Your argument works perfectly. Good job.

Comment: Hint: Proof by induction on $n$.

Comment: Thanks! Out teacher directly told a this property so I couldnt understand. But now I get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to think about it combinatorially: when you multiply
$$(a_1+\cdots + a_n)(a_1+\cdots + a_n)$$
you actually choose one term from the left hand side, multiply it by another term from the r.h.s, and sum all of it up. Thus you have a sum of terms of the form $a_ia_j$  where $1\leq i,j\leq n$, so you can write:
$$(a_1+\cdots + a_n)^2=\sum_i\sum_ja_ia_j$$
Similarly, you can form triple sums by looking at 
$$(a_1+\cdots + a_n)(a_1+\cdots + a_n)(a_1+\cdots + a_n)$$
and this will be a sum of $a_ia_ja_k$ where $1\leq i,j,k\leq n$,
so
$$(a_1+\cdots + a_n)^3=\sum_i\sum_j\sum_ka_ia_ja_k,$$
and so on.

Comment: Yes I tried to write terms and this too verified that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\sum_{i=0}^n(\sum_{j=0}^na_ia_j )=$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^n(a_i\sum_{j=0}^na_j) $$

$$a_0+a_1+...a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k $$

Comment: The OP already said that...

Comment: And it looks like the OP already knows that too...

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n}a_ia_j = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\left(a_ia_0+\dots
+a_ia_n\right)=\left(a_0a_0+\dots
+a_0a_n\right)+\dots +\left(a_na_0+\dots
+a_na_n\right)=\left(a_0+\dots
+a_n\right)^2=\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}a_i\right)^2$